# Keyboard isn't detected on boot, but works after suspend

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, suspend, laptop

When I boot up my system (I'm using Ubuntu 20.04), the keyboard isn't detected. The only way to have it working is to suspend the system and wake it up back. Then the keyboard is fully functioning. I tried using different acpi_osi kernel parameters without success. The same happens with differents Live USB. The keyboard works in BIOS though.

My laptop model is Clevo PB71DF2-G and I fresh installed Ubuntu on it. Everything else works as expected.
Does anyone have a solution ?

Comment: Try the most recent kernel e.g. 5.7.14

Comment: I tried 5.7.1 few days ago and it didn't fix it

Comment: Then file a bug report at https://bugzilla.kernel.org/ - hopefully kernel developers will notice it and resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

in the BIOS, there is a setting that makes the computer boot "faster" at the expense of losing legacy devices like keyboards. Turn this fast boot off, and it will work again.